# Access to the database file is not allowed. 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, filezilla

I've just publish my Web Site via Visual Studio to my Domain name (Combell)...

So, when I try to access to my web site in my web browser, My Web Site works... **BUT when I try to log on I got this error:**

> Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1884,File name = D:\WebSites\tennisonlinebiz\www\App_Data\Tennis.sdf,SeCreateFile ]

I've found one solution in MSDN forum: http://forums.asp.net/t/1698244.aspx/1/10

This solution consists to change the permission property of the APP_Data folder in READ & Write, I've done this with FILEZilla but commands seem wrong:

> CWD /
>   Response :  250 CWD command successful.
>   Command :   SITE CHMOD 777 DAL
>   Response :  500 'SITE CHMOD 777 DAL': command not understood
>   Statut :    Définir les permissions de '/Models' à '777'
>   Command :   SITE CHMOD 777 Models
>   Response :  500 'SITE CHMOD 777 Models': command not understood

Can you help me to find a solution ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have got a full control of my Microsoft Web Server 2008 so was able to change it directly. I have added this user **IIS_IUSRS** for this folder **App_Data** with all permissions except **Full Control**.

I can just guess if you are doing it through ftp, it adds probably Everyone which is ok but you are just not able to do it through FileZilla ftp? Try Total Commander or anything else or contact your provider to add it manually.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more, this was the right fix for me. I had a system that had been working fine but stopped working after a deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user which is configured in IIS to access the physical path of the site. You can check by Test settings option in the Basic settings tab of the site.

Again the configured user should be configued as App pool user.Check the Advanced settings of the App pool which the site runs, and the Identity of the app pool should be the same user which we configured to access the physical path of the site.

This should resolve this error.